# How hibernate register entity classes during JPA style bootstrapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Previously I was using hibernate native bootstrapping, where I explicitly call `addAnnotatedClass` to register my entity classes one by one.

I'm migrating to JPA style bootstrapping, but it's not clear to me how did hibernate recognize and register those entity class? My guess is through the `@Entity` annotation, but is hibernating doing a full scan over all classes? Is there any specification that I need to put the entity class in some specific package with naming conventions to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm) has a nice explanation:

> What Persistent Managed Classes Does This Persistence Unit Include?
>
> You can specify the persistent managed classes associated with a persistence unit by using one or more of the following:
>
> `<mapping-file>` element: specifies one or more object-relational mapping XML files (orm.xml files).
>
> `<jar-file>` element: specifies one or more JAR files that will be searched for classes.
>
> `<class>` element: specifies an explicit list of classes.
>
> The annotated managed persistence classes contained in the root of the persistence unit.
>
> The root of the persistence unit is the JAR file or directory, whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml file. To exclude managed persistence classes, add an `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` element to the persistence unit.

Basically, it will scan the jars containing the `/META-INF/persistence.xml` for classes with the `@Entity` annotation or you can list those classes and set `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` and only the listed ones will be used.

For example:

```
<persistence-unit name="postgresql-example">
    <class>org.hibernate.reactive.example.nativesql.Author</class>
    <class>org.hibernate.reactive.example.nativesql.Book</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```